# How to pass arguments to main function within Python module?

Tags: python, module, arguments, package

I have recently started learning more about Python Packages and Modules. I'm currently busy updating my existing modules so that that can be run as script or imported as a module into my other code. I'm not sure how to construct my input arguments within my module and pass them to the main() function within my module.

I've have written my my **main()** function and called it under **if __name__ == '__main__'** passing the input arguments. The inputs are currently hard coded to show what I'm trying to achieve. Any help in how to correctly construct my input arguments that the user will pass, which will then be passed onto the main function will be appreciated.

As mentioned I'm trying to be able to use the following as a script when used directly or imported as a module into my other code and run from there. If I import it as a module would I call the **main()** function when importing it? Is the following structure correct in how I have written the following? Any advice is appreciated.

```
'''
Created on March 12, 2017

Create a new ArcHydro Schema

File Geodatabase and Rasters

Folder

@author: PeterW
'''
# import site-packages and modules
import re
from pathlib import Path
import arcpy

# set environment settings
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


def archydro_rasters_folder(workspace):
    """Create rasters folder directory
    if it doens't already exist"""
    model_name = Path(workspace).name
    layers_name = re.sub(r"\D+", "Layers", model_name)
    layers_folder = Path(workspace, layers_name)
    if layers_folder.exists():
        arcpy.AddMessage("Rasters folder: {0} exists".format(layers_name))
    else:
        layers_folder.mkdir(parents=True)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Rasters folder {0} created".format(layers_name))


def archydro_fgdb_schema(workspace, schema, dem):
    """Create file geodatabase using XML
    schema and set coordinate system based
    on input DEM if it doesn't already exist"""
    model_name = Path(workspace).name
    fgdb = "{0}.gdb".format(model_name)
    if arcpy.Exists(str(Path(workspace, fgdb))):
        arcpy.AddMessage("{0} file geodatabase exists".format(fgdb))
    else:
        new_fgdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(str(workspace), fgdb)
        import_type = "SCHEMA_ONLY"
        config_keyword = "DEFAULTS"
        arcpy.AddMessage("New {0} file geodatabase created".format(fgdb))
        arcpy.ImportXMLWorkspaceDocument_management(new_fgdb, schema,
                                                    import_type,
                                                    config_keyword)
        arcpy.AddMessage("ArcHydro schema imported")
        projection = arcpy.Describe(dem).spatialReference
        projection_name = projection.PCSName
        feature_dataset = Path(workspace, fgdb, "Layers")
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(str(feature_dataset),
                                          projection)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Changed projection to {0}".format(projection_name))


def main(workspace, dem, schema):
    """main function to create rasters folder
    and file geodatabase"""
    archydro_rasters_folder(workspace)
    archydro_fgdb_schema(schema, dem, workspace)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(workspace = r"E:\Projects\2016\01_Bertrand_Small_Projects\G113268\ArcHydro\Model04",
         dem = r"E:\Projects\2016\01_Bertrand_Small_Projects\G113268\ArcHydro\DEM2\raw",
         schema = r"E:\Python\Masters\Schema\ESRI_UC12\ModelBuilder\Schema\Model01.xml")
```

Updated: 17/03/13

The following is my updated Python module based on Jonathan's suggestions:

```
'''
Created on March 12, 2017

Create a new ArcHydro Schema

File Geodatabase and Rasters

Folder

@author: PeterW
'''
# import site-packages and modules
import re
from pathlib import Path
import arcpy
import argparse

# set environment settings
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


def rasters_directory(workspace):
    """Create rasters folder directory
    if it doens't already exist"""
    model_name = Path(workspace).name
    layers_name = re.sub(r"\D+", "Layers", model_name)
    layers_folder = Path(workspace, layers_name)
    if layers_folder.exists():
        arcpy.AddMessage("Rasters folder: {0} exists".format(layers_name))
    else:
        layers_folder.mkdir(parents=True)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Rasters folder {0} created".format(layers_name))


def fgdb_schema(workspace, schema, dem):
    """Create file geodatabase using XML
    schema and set coordinate system based
    on input DEM if it doesn't already exist"""
    model_name = Path(workspace).name
    fgdb = "{0}.gdb".format(model_name)
    if arcpy.Exists(str(Path(workspace, fgdb))):
        arcpy.AddMessage("{0} file geodatabase exists".format(fgdb))
    else:
        new_fgdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(str(workspace), fgdb)
        import_type = "SCHEMA_ONLY"
        config_keyword = "DEFAULTS"
        arcpy.AddMessage("New {0} file geodatabase created".format(fgdb))
        arcpy.ImportXMLWorkspaceDocument_management(new_fgdb, schema,
                                                    import_type,
                                                    config_keyword)
        arcpy.AddMessage("ArcHydro schema imported")
        projection = arcpy.Describe(dem).spatialReference
        projection_name = projection.PCSName
        feature_dataset = Path(workspace, fgdb, "Layers")
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(str(feature_dataset),
                                          projection)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Changed projection to {0}".format(projection_name))


def model_schema(workspace, schema, dem):
    """Create model schema: rasters folder
    and file geodatabase"""
    rasters_directory(workspace)
    fgdb_schema(schema, dem, workspace)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create a ArcHydro schema')
    parser.add_argument('--workspace', metavar='path', required=True,
                        help='the path to workspace')
    parser.add_argument('--schema', metavar='path', required=True,
                        help='path to schema')
    parser.add_argument('--dem', metavar='path', required=True,
                        help='path to dem')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    model_schema(workspace=args.workspace, schema=args.schema, dem=args.dem)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This looks correct to me, and yes if you're looking to use this as a module you would import main. Though, it would probably be better to name it in a more descriptive way.

To clarify how `__main__` and the function `main()` works. When you execute a module it will have a name which is stored in `__name__`. If you execute the module stand alone as a script it will have the name `__main__`. If you execute it as part of a module ie import it into another module it will have the name of the module.

The function `main()` can be named anything you would like, and that wouldn't affect your program. It's commonly named `main` in small scripts but it's not a particularly good name if it's part of a larger body of code.

In terms letting a user to input arguments when running as a script I would look into either using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/why/)

An example of how argparse would work.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create a ArcHydro schema')
    parser.add_argument('--workspace', metavar='path', required=True,
                        help='the path to workspace')
    parser.add_argument('--schema', metavar='path', required=True,
                        help='path to schema')
    parser.add_argument('--dem', metavar='path', required=True,
                        help='path to dem')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(workspace=args.workspace, schema=args.schema, dem=args.dem)
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the following. So my main() function doesn't have to be called main?

Comment: nope, you can call it whatever you like. I updated the answer to include some more detail :)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, would you be able to give me an example how to pass the arguments using argparse to my main() funciton. The reason for asking is that I call two functions within my main() func that use the argument workspace.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include how to use argparse.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I can't thank you enough, you have been a great help. The following is going to nelp me a lot with my code going forward.

Comment: What's the benefit of having import inside the function instead of outside it?

Comment: @Zypps987 no particular in this case. In some cases you it might be useful because you're fulfilling some requirements and unless fulfilled you can't make the import.

Comment: @PeterWilson If the python file has command line arguments like ```--config_file path_to_file```, who can they be passed while directly calling the main function?

Comment: @PiyushShandilya It would be passed to the  argument that you have associated the command line argument with. It might help posting a separate question on StackOverflow with an example of your code to help you further.